# Is there any counter to incendiary shotgun rounds?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

Keep dying to these rounds and it's annoying because it seems there's no counter. If I get grazed, I'll eventually burn to death, if I get direct impacted, then death is close and near.

I've looked through the perk list and through the different divisions and can't find a class that would have a perk or ability of sorts to resist fire damage, so long story short, is there a counter to incendiary rounds?

Comment: Jump into the water?

Comment: Since the game is currently in "beta"/demo form and not everything is available as it would be in the full game. Wait until November when the game is released and Post-beta changes have been made.

Comment: @Rapitor I disagree with your close vote. We've had questions on betas in the past that have been fine. If anything, this question can stand for the beta, and a new one could be applicable once the game releases. This isn't unreleased content.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 Most maps don't have water, or the fact that the "water" is an out of bounds zone and is thus you falling to your death.

Comment: Distance and reaction time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only real counter measure you can take against fire rounds is to play as an Armored Division soldier and rank the division up to level 3.  At level 3, you take less fire damage.

In game, this is denoted by a flame icon in the middle of your screen.  When you are on fire, this icon will appear, indicating that your less fire damage perk is kicking in.

Besides that, it's a matter of being able to take out your opposition faster than they can shoot you.  Also note that keeping your distance as pointed out in the comments is a good idea, since these rounds are shot from shotguns only, which have a short range.

Comment: Also note that the only water I know of in online play kills you instantly for jumping in it (London Docks level).